# How to create automatic carousel slider in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel, setinterval

I am in beginning of building the carousel in pure JavaScript. First, I am trying to implement automatic slider every 2 seconds. Here is the code:

```
var num = 0;
var intervalID;
window.onload = function() {
var link = document.getElementById("toTest");
link.onclick = marChange;


intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
link.click();
}, 2000);


}

function marChange(intervalID) {
window.setTimeout(function() {
num = num+900;
var element = document.getElementById("adjust");
var margin = "-"+num+"px";
element.style.marginLeft = margin;
}, 2000);

}
```

Currently what I have is this: function waits for 4 seconds and changes 1 slide, after that it continues to change slides with 0 seconds timeout. I am struggling badly to understand what I am doing wrong - I tried all the tips already I could find on the web, but result is always the same. Even when I am trying to clear interval like that:

```
if(num>=1800) {
window.clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

Nothing happens. It seems like I am invoking the interval, but unable to manipulate it any further.

If anyone knows how this can be resolved, please help me.

Thank you.